# How to speed up sonarqube analysis job?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, code-analysis, static-analysis, sonarqube-scan

I have one java based application which is having huge line of source code(~1m).Now I am using **jenkins** with [sonar-runner-2.4](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Runner) to run analysis with code coverage and test cases count.I have upgraded sonarqube server from `5.4` to `6.3.1`.Before upgrade this job took `9hrs` to complete the whole analysis (still it is very much long time but fine) but after upgrade to `sonarqube-6.3.1` same job taking `13hrs` to complete the same analysis.

How do I improve analysis time at least my earlier time `9hr` ?

**EDIT**

Here is my `JAVA_OPTS` for `sonarqube-6.3.1` instance

```
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx6G -Xms2G -XX:MaxPermSize=1G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

**Available Hardware** :

$lscpu 

`Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 26
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               1596.000
BogoMIPS:              3999.44
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     4-7`

**Available Memory** :
`$free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         128714       58945       66232         430        3535       68298
Swap:         32767         957       31810`

**sonar-project.properties for the long running job:**

[sonar-project.properties](https://pastebin.com/Nx9fHY20)

Comment: 9hrs is a lot! It shouldn't take that long. Are you following the [hardware requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements)?

Comment: Hi @Teryk-SonarSourceTeam Thank you for your guidance!  I have updated my question with hardware configuration I have and `sonar-project.properties` can you please guide where I have done something wrong ?

Comment: Currently I have oracle Database of `10GB` can you please help me how frequently we should `re-index` or `purge` it ?

Comment: @Teryk-SonarSourceTeam can you please take a look in properties file and help me where should I need to make change ??

Answer (score 3):

As you haven't really given many details, I can't really give many details in the answer, but the simple answer is that you have to make the scan do less work.

Look at your codebase.  Is your scan processing generated classes?  Is it scanning test classes?  Is it scanning classes that have little real business logic?  If you answer "yes" to any of those, consider excluding those classes.

Look at the SonarQube plugins you're using.  Are you running every possible plugin you can run?  Are there some heuristics you don't need to run, or perhaps you could run less frequently?

Comment: HI @David, Thank you for your answer ! I have updated the details in my question. Can you please help me for same ? also let me know if you need any further details.Thank you!